# Difference between build.gradle and integration.gradle

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

In an external project, I have found various `build.gradle` files and one `integration.gradle`. What is the difference between the latter and the formers, apart the name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One `build.gradle` file is automatically assigned to each (sub-)project in a Gradle build. The name is the default, but it can be changed in the `settings.gradle` file. This is the first possibility how the file called `integration.gradle` could be used. The second possibility is that the file provides  functionality used by one or more projects and gets referenced via `apply from:` somewhere in a `build.gradle` file.